# Set layout margine with float value in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile

I want to set margin of Imageview. What I wanted to achieve is to move one image up to some distance. The content of screen is RelativeLayout, in that there is ImageView at left and button at right aligned. Now I want to move image from left to right within the gap between Image and Button in 100 click of button. The code I am following is as below:

```
private static int count= 1 ;

public void onClick(View view) {


    RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    ImageView i1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageButton btn= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.iBtn);

    int i1Width = i1.getWidth();
    int btnWidth = btn.getWidth();
    int totalMragine = lay.getWidth() - i1Width - btnWidth ; //the total margine image will move.
    int stepSize =  (lay.getWidth() - i1Width - btnWidth ) / 100;   
    int step = stepSize * count++;  

    Log.i("i1Width ", ""+i1Width );
    Log.i("btnWidth ", ""+btnWidth );
    Log.i("lay.getWidth()", ""+lay.getWidth());     
    Log.i("stepSize", ""+stepSize);     
    Log.i("count", ""+count);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(step, 0, 0, 0);
    i1.setLayoutParams(lp);     

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) horse.getLayoutParams();
    Log.i("currentMargine", ""+lp1.leftMargin);

    if(lp1.leftMargin >= totalMragine ){
        Log.i("Result", "maringe over");
    }
}
```

What I wanted to know that the margin I am setting is in Integer but the value for the step is in float. So How to set margin float in LayoutParams? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: is values after decimal  important ? is round off them not fine?

Comment: no. for e.g gap between btn and img is 370. so the step size is 370 / 100. which should be 3.7 but as it is Integer it gives 3 as a step. What actually it should move is 3.7px per step.

Comment: gr8.....it's interesting now.......

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing calculate distance to move every time as when going to move

distance to move =  the rest of length/rest of clicks

of in final step (100th step) it will reach to end with error < **.** 5px and **.** 5px is too small  )

like in

```
1st click  distance_to_move = 370/100;   as round off come 4 

2nd click  distance_to_move = 366/99;    as round off come 4 

3rd click  distance_to_move = 362/98;    as round off come 4
```

so movemnt will be as in px 44444...3444...3444..3444...